# Mobile page loading in "zoomed" state

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, chart.js

I'm having an issue trying to make my portfolio more responsive on mobile. What is happening is on initial load the page is presented in a "zoomed in" state. I can zoom out and see the site as its supposed to be. The navbar seems to take up the proper width, but all elements below are significantly *wider* for no reasons I can really find.

The current code is all up to date at https://codespent.dev for inspection so I won't clutter this question with code, I'll add the relevant code as we troubleshoot.

[image]

**What I've tried:**

Tried adding viewport metadata to [restrict scaling & set the initial scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272420/webpage-starts-zoomed-in-on-mobile-devices).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalabe=0;">
```

Verified there's no static widths on elements to the best of my knowledge.

Confirmed the [reported *device-width* is accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756949/why-do-mobile-browsers-load-my-page-completely-zoomed-in) but elements still obtrude the widths.

**Findings:**

Canvas in charts is causing the document width to obtrude from setting `responsive: true;` which ignores heights and widths.

- Fixed this by setting a `max-width: 250px` on `canvas` to prevent expanding from misreads of device-width.

The typewriter code strings that overflow cause the width to expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas element inside your graph has a fixed width of 2000px.

Comment: That's a result of setting `responsive: true` for [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) so I'm thinking that could be it. Let me try overriding with a max-width.

Comment: Okay so yeah, its most definitely the Charts that are causing the issue which I didn't see at first because setting the Chart to responsive ignores my widths.